# youtube.com/get_video_info returning 404

Tags: youtube

In my downloader I used `www.youtube.com/get_video_info` to get things like the title, views, description, etc. About 1 month ago that didn't work anymore and returned 404. I then found out you just have to add a few arguments, with the url beeing then `https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?html5=1&c=TVHTML5&cver=6.20180913&video_id=<video id>`.

Now that doesn't work again. Does anyone know what the new URL is? I already tried to change the `cver` value as it seems to be a version of the API or something.